# Is there any way to run perticular scenario in karate more than one time if specific condition met true?

Tags: bdd, karate

I want to run my perticular scenario or feature file more than one time.

Let's say if user enter 5 then i want my url to be hit 5 times.

is it possible in karate? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Yes, read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#loops

But also see example below using [dynamic scenario outlines](https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline):

EDIT: using a `Background` will not work in Karate 1.3.0 onwards, please refer to this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75155712/143475

```
Background:
* def fun = function(i){ return { name: 'User ' + (i + 1) } }
* def data = karate.repeat(5, fun)

Scenario Outline:
* url 'http://httpbin.org/anything'
* request __row
* method post

Examples:
| data |
```

So run this, see how it works and study how it works as well.

Note that [data driven features](https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features) is an alternate approach where you can [`call`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files) a second feature file in a loop. So for example after using `karate.repeat()` 5 times like in the above `Background`, you use `data` as the argument to a second feature file that hits your url.

Comment: Hi Peter, I have tried running above example but getting below error variable 'data' is not defined. Seems like 'data' variable reference in Examples throwing error. Complete error info - *
 
src/test/java/features/sample.feature[1:13] dynamic expression evaluation failed: data
0
js failed:
>>>>
01: data
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "data" is not defined
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)

Comment: @sanjaypujari see my edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75155712/143475

Comment: Thank you! Peter. It worked with the above changes you mentioned in edit.