# karate: Dynamic Scenario Outline not working when json is defined in background

Tags: dynamic, cucumber, karate, outline, scenarios

```
Feature: Dynamic Scenario Outline
 Background: 
  * def kittens = [{"name":"abc"},{"name":"def"}]
 Scenario Outline: cat name: <name> 
  * print <name> 
 Examples: 
  | kittens |
```

error after executing this code is:

```
 org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "kittens" is not defined
```

Whereas, if I put this JSON directly into examples, this is working and executing 2 time. passing as shown below:

```
Examples: 
  | [{"name":"abc"},{"name":"def"}] |
```

why am i getting "kittens" is not defined, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Background` does not work like this in new versions of Karate.

Please read: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/releases/tag/v1.3.0

So try:

```
Feature:

@setup
Scenario:
* def kittens = [{"name":"abc"},{"name":"def"}]  

 Scenario Outline: cat name: <name> 
  * print name 
 Examples: 
  | karate.setup().kittens |
```

Comment: working nicely if I implement a setup. but the new problem arising is, when I run this test, a total of 3 scenarios are executing two for kittens, and one for setup itself. in the report, 3 scenarios are shown, whereas I want a count of only 2 scenarios to be shown in the report. how can i handle this?

Comment: @Snehithtammewar https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/releases/tag/v1.3.1 - and if you can, use 1.4.0.RC3 which may have more fixes