# Karate : How to refer or read variable in Examples section which is defined in Scenario Outline

Tags: karate, bdd

In karate framework, I am trying refer variable in Examples section which is defined in Scenario Outline. Below is the code snippet of feature file.

```
Scenario Outline:
* print __row
* def data = read('test.csv')    
* def selected = 'TRUE'
* def fun = function(x){ return x.Status == selected }
* def filtered = karate.filter(data, fun)
* print filtered

Examples:
    | filtered |
```

After I execute this, getting below error.

*js failed:

org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: **ReferenceError: "filtered" is not defined***

Can any one please let me know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

The `Scenario Outline` is the last thing to take control so you need to understand the flow. Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75155712/143475

Maybe you should get a normal `Scenario Outline` to work before trying advanced things. Take some time to read the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#data-driven-tests